# ASP.NET Mvc Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I wrote something like this in the controller.

```
   public ActionResult Giris()

    {

        ViewData["Tarif"] = (from t in _entities.Tarif

                             join k in _entities.Kullanici on t.KID equals k.KID

                             select new {KAdi = k.KAdi, TAdi = t.TAdi})

                             .Take(4);



        return View();

    }
```

I am using it as below in the view page.

```
<% foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewData["Tarif"]) {  %>

<div class="begenilen-video" style="float:left">

<img class="video-resmi" alt="reklam" src="../../Uygulama/Resimler/Reklam/1.jpg" />

<span class="benzer-yemek-tarifi-adi"></span><%=item.TAdi %><br />

<span class="benzer-yemek-tarifi-ekleyen">Ekleyen: </span><br />

<span class="benzer-yemek-tarifi-izlenme">İzlenme: </span>

</div>

<% } %>
```

However,I am receive the error in the select statement.How do I invoke the items in the view page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As a guess because you haven't posted the error:*

The object being stored in `ViewData["Tarif"]` will be of the type `IQueryable<T>` where T is an anonymous object and in your view you are casting to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.  `IQueryable` is also lazily loaded so you will be trying to execute your query once the object has been disposed.

You should really create a strongly typed view model

```
public class ViewModelType {

  public IEnumerable<TarifType> Tarif { get; set; }

}
```

Tarif type

```
public class TarifType {

  public string KAdi { get; set; }
  public string TAdi { get; set; }

}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Giris() {

  var viewModel = new ViewModelType();

  viewModel.Tarif = (from t in _entities.Tarif
                       join k in _entities.Kullanici on t.KID equals k.KID
                       select new TraifType { KAdi = k.KAdi, TAdi = t.TAdi }
                     ).Take(4)
                     .ToList();

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

view

```
<% foreach (var item in viewModel.Tarif) {  %>
  <div class="begenilen-video" style="float:left">
    <img class="video-resmi" alt="reklam" src="../../Uygulama/Resimler/Reklam/1.jpg" />
    <span class="benzer-yemek-tarifi-adi"></span><%=item.TAdi %><br />
    <span class="benzer-yemek-tarifi-ekleyen">Ekleyen: </span><br />
    <span class="benzer-yemek-tarifi-izlenme">İzlenme: </span>
  </div>
<% } %>
```